# How to mount an encrypted volume from an external harddrive on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, usb, encryption, mount

I would like to have some encrypted volumes from an external (USB) disk mounted during boot on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have tried:

1. cryptsetup:
   It runs before the usb disk is mounted and therefore fails.
2. systemd:
   I configured: WantedBy=media-niels-NielsData07.mount and enabled the service, but it is not triggered when the disk is mounted.
3. udev:
   Udev runs before the disk is mounted.
4. cron:
   Cron runs too late.

Please let me know how I can configure Ubuntu 18.04 to mount encrypted volumes from an external USB disk as soon as it is mounted during boot.

Answer (score 0):

systemd is the correct method to use, and the following code works for me:

```
cat -> encrypted_volumes.service
[Unit]
Description=Mount the encrypted volumes

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/encrypted_volumes.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=media-niels-NielsData07.mount

cp encrypted_volumes.sh /usr/local/bin/.
cp encrypted_volumes.service /lib/systemd/system/.

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable encrypted_volumes.service
```